# Why does the R class not contain the field type?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever we want to inflate a view or get a resource we have to cast it in run-time. views, for example, are used like so:

In the past, we would have needed to cast it locally

```
(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout_view)
```

Now, we use generics

```
findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.my_relative_layout_view)
```

my question is why doesn't the compiler(or whoever generates the R class) doesn't also keep some kind of a reference to the type of the element(doesn't matter if it's a string or an int or any other type) that way casting problems should not occur

Answer (score 1):

We cannot really speculate on that, that would be a design choice.

It *might* be that they wanted to avoid bloating the APK. Every ID would need a full package name to the class. So would each ID in android.R too. Since R is packaged in every APK.

## Solutions

However, if you are using Kotlin, you can even do away with the generics check. Kotlin will determine it automatically.

```
val view = findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout_view)
view.method()
```

Or event simpler, if you use synthetics:

```
my_relative_layout_view.method()
```

Also, if you are using data bindings, you can just access it like this:

```
binding.my_relative_layout_view.method()
```